# OnActivityResult in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I'm developing an android application that is dependent on maps and location.
I have `ActivityA` that contains `fragmentA`.

I have an alert that request the user to turn on location service inside `fragmentA`.
When the user accept to turn on the service, I want my code to continue running, otherwise `finish()` the app. So I should use `OnActivityResult()` to know what did the user pressed in the alert.
My problem is that when the user accept to turn on Location, the function `OnActivityResult()` is launched in the activity and not in the fragment.
I read about this problem, people are suggesting to call `startActivityForResult(...)` rather than `startActivity(...)`.
But I can't start the activity from an inside fragment because this will lead to crash problems regarding data that are in the intent.
So any one has any suggestions ?
This is the function that requests Location in `fragmentA`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment.

Comment: @ADM I saw this post and I think they're talking about getting results from another activity, my problem is getting result from same activity.

Comment: `But I can't start the activity from an inside fragment because this will lead to crash problems ` ? Whats this suppose to mean ?  While you can use `startActivityForResult()` from fragment ?

Comment: I'm starting the activity (ActivityA) from another activity (ActivityB), and sending data in the intent and getting them in `ActivityA`, so when i call `startActivityForResult()` from fragment, the data inside the intent are nulls. I can know if I'm starting the activity (ActivityA) from `ActivityB` or from the fragment (fragmentA) but I'm searching on a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent( getActivity(), yourClass.class );
getActivity().startActivity(intent);